# How can I in a query calculate the sum of the union

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

this is what I did and in the image the result now I want to get the sum of all group by UserSend for example
you can see that maorsapo@gmail.com 
have 7 and 3 in the second
I want that Instead of this
it will be maorsapo@gmail.com, 10(7+3)
how can I do this?

```
SELECT m.UserSend, Count(*) AS Expr1
FROM Messages AS m
GROUP BY m.UserSend;
union
SELECT F.UserRequest, Count(*) AS Expr1
FROM FavoritesList AS F
GROUP BY F.UserRequest;
```

https://ibb.co/cbuKrJ

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a sum of the resulting table

```
select t.my_user, sum(Expr1)
from (
    SELECT m.UserSend as  my_user, Count(*) AS Expr1
    FROM Messages AS m
    GROUP BY m.UserSend;
    union
    SELECT F.UserRequest, Count(*) AS Expr1
    FROM FavoritesList AS F
    GROUP BY F.UserRequest;
) t 
group by t.my_user
```

Answer (score 0):

You want `union all` rather than `union`:

```
SELECT user, sum(cnt)
FROM (SELECT m.UserSend as user, Count(*) AS cnt
      FROM Messages AS m
      GROUP BY m.UserSend;
      UNION ALL
      SELECT F.UserRequest, Count(*) AS cnt
      FROM FavoritesList AS F
      GROUP BY F.UserRequest
     ) as u
GROUP BY user;
```

`UNION` will remove duplicates, which you don't want to do.

I recall that some older versions of MS Access required a view to accomplish this, because `union`/`union all` was not allowed in subqueries.  But this should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

thank you very much
SELECT user, sum(cnt)
FROM (SELECT m.UserSend as user, Count(*) AS cnt
      FROM Messages AS m
      GROUP BY m.UserSend;
      UNION ALL
      SELECT F.UserRequest, Count(*) AS cnt
      FROM FavoritesList AS F
      GROUP BY F.UserRequest
     ) as u
GROUP BY user;